# PHP mysql ID to username in different tables

Tags: php, html, sql, database, mysqli

Here is example of a database. We call this database table `Player`:

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
| Name    | pid      | cash        | bankacc    | Random     |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|    carl | 123      | non         | 3434343434 |   34343433 |  |
|  petter | 456      | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
|     sam | 1337     | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
|         |          | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
```

Here is another table called `House`; in house is only display the `PID`:

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
| pid     | owned    | pos         | random     | Random     |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|     123 | categ    | non         | 3434343434 |   34343433 |  |
|     456 | categ    | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
|    1337 | tag      | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
|       4 | tag      | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
```

I'm trying to display this table called "House" in my php site, but I do not want to display the "pid" instead of "pid" I want the name of the house owner.

```
$sql = "SELECT pid, pos, owned FROM houses";
$ru = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = $ru->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['pid'].'</td>'; <--instead of pid I want the name in here
        echo '<td>'.$row['pos'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['owned'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="text-right">';
        echo '<button class="button tiny">View User</button>';
        echo '<button class="button alert tiny">Delete</button>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

But here is example of a query how I want it. Really bad example.

```
$sql = "SELECT pid = name, pos, owned FROM houses, player";
```

Comment: Explain more about your question. What is the out put you relay want.

Comment: use `INNER JOIN` in your sql statement.

Comment: You need to read a SQL tutorial, not just write code randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use join to get the name from player table

```
SELECT player.name, house.pos, house.owned 
FROM houses house
LEFT JOIN player player on player.pid=house.pid
```

code

```
$sql = "SELECT player.`name` as owner_name, hs.pos, hs.owned 
FROM houses hs
LEFT JOIN player pl on pl.pid=hs.pid";
$ru = $conn->query($sql);


while ($row = $ru->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['owner_name'].'</td>'; <--instead of pid i want the name in here
    echo '<td>'.$row['pos'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['owned'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-right">';
    echo '<button class="button tiny">View User</button>';
    echo '<button class="button alert tiny">Delete</button>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

MySQL fetch Row Tutorial:  https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_row.asp

some notes:

better to change the column 'name' to 'owner_name' to avoid any conflicts or use backticks(`) around column names when you use reserved keywords in query:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys i got it work :)

This is the working code how i changed it a bit

```
$sql = "SELECT players.name as owner_name, houses.pos, houses.owned FROM houses LEFT JOIN players ON players.pid=houses.pid";
$ru = $conn->query($sql);


while ($row = $ru->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['owner_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['pos'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['owned'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-right">';
    echo '<button class="button tiny">View User</button>';
    echo '<button class="button alert tiny">Delete</button>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```